# Get content from RSS file

Tags: php, rss

I tried to get content from rss file

by do the following

```
$xml="Podcast/Cast/waraq/podcast.xml";
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->load($xml);
$items= $dom->getElementsByTagName('item');

 foreach ($items as $item) {

   $title=$item->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
   $pubDate=$item->getElementsByTagName('pubDate')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
   $category=$item->getElementsByTagName('category')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
   $description=$item->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
   $subtitle=$item->getElementsByTagName('itunes:subtitle')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
}
```

put this line cause error ;

```
$subtitle=$item->getElementsByTagName('itunes:subtitle')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

and I note that every element have ":" in it's name cause error.

so how can I retrieve element that has ":" in it's name

many thank

Comment: You can't. a `:` is not a valid part of a node name, because it's used to signify an XML namespace. `<itunes:subtitle>` is a `<subtitle>` tag that's in the `itunes` namespace.

Comment: put how can I retrieve this tag
I tried this put also it cause error 
$subtitle=$item->getElementsByTagName('subtitle')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
}

it seem that they does not found it !!

Comment: thank i found the solution 

$feed = file_get_contents("Podcast/Cast/waraq/podcast.xml");
$xml = new SimpleXmlElement($feed);
foreach ($xml->channel->item as $entry){
  //echo $entry->title;
  //echo $entry->description;
  
  $itunes= $entry->children('http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd');
  echo $itunes->subtitle;

}